# Installing provision profile

Tags: ios

I have problem with installing the provisional profile from the web view. The profile is enterprise one. I'll load a web page in the safari and if i click install button on the page in safari, from the server the profile is downloaded and then it is installed. But If the same web page is opened in the webView then there will be a error(Frame load something :( ) but I was able to collect the response object and the data coming from the server but I am not able to install by using the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:];. Will someone help me on this please. I dont know how safari does that but I am not able to do the same. PLease any one help if it can be done . Or please tell me it cant be done and suggest me alternate ways.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari has access to the iOS Certificate/Profile store. UIWebView does not. You cannot install configuration or provisioning profiles via a UIWebView. In fact, you cannot install them through any API. It's only IPCU/Safari.